# Delay while printing from iOS app using Epson TM -m30 thermal printer

Tags: ios, swift, thermal-printer, epson

I am developing one POS app in which we are giving functionalities to print ticket/receipt using EPSON TM - m30 thermal printer.

I can connect with the printer easily. **But I am facing one issue that it prints ticket/receipt with some delay (after 5-6 secs).**

I am using this iOS SDK - https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5670&scat=58&pcat=52

Steps:

1) Initialize printer

2) preparing print-data

3) Connecting to printer

4) Begin transaction

5) Send data

After printing data successfully 
1) Ending transaction

2) Disconnecting to printer

3) Clear buffer

4) set printer to nil

This whole process is taking 5-6 seconds to complete.  So what is the best way to print data with minimal time.   Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explicit a little what operation exactly is taking time? And add some code for each action? Maybe some of them can be done in background? If the sending data is the culprit it may be not optimizable on your part.

Comment: I cant figure it out which operation is taking more time. Actually before starting operation I am setting print button's alpha to 0.5 , but even this operation is also taking some time to set alpha to 0.5

Comment: "I am setting print button's alpha to 0.5 , but even this operation is also taking some time to set alpha to 0.5" What? What's your code? It seems you are blocking your main thread with long operations...

Comment: After clicking on print button - first I am setting its alpha to 0.5 then I am following above steps which is mentioned in Epson ios SDK and then after successfully printing again I am setting alpha to 1 , I cant understand why this is happening

Comment: Without code, it's hard to guess what's wrong. And you could print some logs with dates to know what's taking time (or use the Instrument's Time Profiler).